# Where are downloaded files stored?

Tags: filesystem, downloads, install-from-source

Today I installed 12.10 as my second OS. I made all updates and upgrades. Then I downloaded  `crunch-3.4tgz` and `fern-wifi-cracker 1.6 all.deb` but I could nowhere find these files to be able to install the applications.

Searching Ask Ubuntu did not help me. Everytime I follow any guide I get the error `no such file or directory`.

My box seems not to see these files even though I had placed them on my desktop.

Where can I find them?

Comment: english please.

Comment: Please note that this site is English only.

Comment: that's the german translation of his question.

Answer (score 2):

The file should go to your Download directory. Try `ls -a ~/Downloads` and see if your file is there.

If its not there for some reason you can use the find command to locate it.
`find $HOME -iname crunch-3.4tgz`

You can also search in the graphical interface, Nautilus.